# Unknown option: .module. in Babel and ESLint setup

Tags: javascript, reactjs, babeljs, eslint

I'm encountering an issue with my Babel and ESLint setup in a React project. When I run ESLint, I get the following error:

```
Line 0: Parsing error: Unknown option: .module. Check out https://babeljs.io/docs/en/babel-core/#options for more information about options
```

Here are the relevant parts of my configuration files:

babel.config.js

```
module.exports = {
  module: {
    rules: [
      {
        test: /\.(js|jsx)$/,
        exclude: /node_modules/,
        use: {
          loader: "babel-loader",
          options: {
            presets: ["@babel/preset-react", [
              "@babel/preset-env",
              {
                "useBuiltIns": "entry",
                "corejs": "3.22"
              }
            ]],
            plugins: ["@babel/plugin-proposal-optional-chaining"],
          },
        },
      },
    ],
  },
};
```

.eslintrc

```
 module.exports = {
      parser: "@babel/eslint-parser",
      parserOptions: {
        requireConfigFile: false,
        babelOptions: {
          presets: ["@babel/preset-env", "@babel/preset-react"],
        },
      },
    };
```

I've checked the Babel documentation but couldn't find a solution. Any help in resolving this issue would be greatly appreciated. Thank you!

here's my package.json file

```
 {
      "name": "memory",
      "version": "0.1.0",
      "private": true,
      "dependencies": {
        "@softbind/react-hooks": "^0.0.3",
        "@testing-library/jest-dom": "^5.17.0",
        "@testing-library/react": "^13.4.0",
        "@testing-library/user-event": "^13.5.0",
        "lodash.shuffle": "^4.2.0",
        "normalize.css": "^8.0.1",
        "prop-types": "^15.8.1",
        "react": "^18.2.0",
        "react-dom": "^18.2.0",
        "react-helmet": "^6.1.0",
        "react-router-dom": "^6.20.0",
        "react-scratchcard": "^1.1.2",
        "react-scripts": "^5.0.1",
        "react-sound": "^1.2.0",
        "react-spring": "^9.7.3",
        "react-tsparticles": "^2.12.2",
        "styled-components": "^6.1.1",
        "tailwind.macro": "^0.5.10",
        "tsparticles": "^2.12.0",
        "tsparticles-slim": "^2.12.0",
        "typescript": "^5.3.2",
        "use-machine": "^1.1.3",
        "web-vitals": "^2.1.4",
        "xstate": "^4.38.3"
      },
      "scripts": {
        "start": "react-scripts start",
        "build": "react-scripts build",
        "test": "react-scripts test",
        "eject": "react-scripts eject"
      },
      "eslintConfig": {
        "extends": [
          "react-app",
          "react-app/jest"
        ]
      },
      "browserslist": {
        "production": [
          ">0.2%",
          "not dead",
          "not op_mini all"
        ],
        "development": [
          "last 1 chrome version",
          "last 1 firefox version",
          "last 1 safari version"
        ]
      },
      "devDependencies": {
        "@babel/core": "^7.23.5",
        "@babel/plugin-proposal-optional-chaining": "7.21.0",
        "@babel/plugin-syntax-object-rest-spread": "^7.8.3",
        "@babel/preset-env": "7.23.5",
        "@babel/preset-react": "7.23.3",
        "@iconify/icons-raphael": "1.2.3",
        "@iconify/react": "4.1.1",
        "babel-plugin-macros": "3.1.0",
        "babel-plugin-styled-components": "2.1.4",
        "eslint": "^8.54.0",
        "eslint-config-airbnb": "19.0.4",
        "eslint-config-prettier": "9.0.0",
        "eslint-plugin-import": "2.29.0",
        "eslint-plugin-jsx-a11y": "6.8.0",
        "eslint-plugin-prettier": "5.0.1",
        "eslint-plugin-react": "7.33.2",
        "husky": "8.0.3",
        "lint-staged": "15.1.0",
        "prettier": "3.1.0"
      }
    }
```

Comment: If you are using `module.exports` in your ESLint config file, then I believe the filename needs to be `.eslintrc.js` not `.eslintrc`. I'm not completely sure if this is what's causing your issue though, is there a full stack trace you can share along with the error?

Comment: @awarrier99 I'm using .eslintrc.js itself.

Comment: Ok, in the post you have shown `.eslintrc` that's why I suggested that. Are there any more details provided with the error? I copy pasted your config files into my own setup and was able to use them as-is with no problems, so I can't seem to reproduce what you have shown

Comment: Ah I think I see the issue actually, your `babel.config.js` looks like it's supposed to be a webpack config. That's why it's complaining about `module` because that is not an expected field in the babel config

Answer (score 0):

Your `babel.config.js` does not contain a valid configuration that the Babel tool can process. More information on what their config files should look like can be found [here](https://babeljs.io/docs/configuration). Instead what you have included is supposed to be used in a [Webpack config](https://webpack.js.org/configuration/). If you rename your `babel.config.js` to a `webpack.config.js` it will likely work (assuming you're using Webpack). If you aren't using Webpack, you will need to convert the config into one that Babel can process. Something like:

```js
module.exports = {
  presets: [
    "@babel/preset-react",
    [
      "@babel/preset-env",
      {
        useBuiltIns: "entry",
        corejs: "3.22",
      }
    ]
  ],
  plugins: ["@babel/plugin-proposal-optional-chaining"]
};
```

Sidenote, since your config file is simple and doesn't actually make use of JS, this could be converted to a JSON configuration file, like `babel.config.json`.